Navigate To Pose and Pause Near Goal-Obstacle Doesn't Work
ROS Version: Humble
I'm trying to import a new .xml file to my bt_navigator in Turtlebot3 Simulation. I'm following this tutorial.
I've tried to copy the same .xml file from the tutorial but I had to remove error_code_id's because Humble Nav2 doesn't support error_code_id ports.
You can check the providedPorts() of the main and Humble branches from these links:
Main Branch
Humble Branch
The rest of the file is the same... I named my file nav_to_pose_and_pause_near_goal_obstacle.xml.
I've changed the default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml from bt_navigator's parameters and set the value to <path_to>nav_to_pose_and_pause_near_goal_obstacle.xml
nav_to_pose_and_pause_near_goal_obstacle.xml:
<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
  <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
    <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="6" name="NavigateRecovery">
      <PipelineSequence name="NavigateWithReplanning">
        <ControllerSelector selected_controller="{selected_controller}" default_controller="FollowPath" topic_name="controller_selector"/>
        <PlannerSelector selected_planner="{selected_planner}" default_planner="GridBased" topic_name="planner_selector"/>
        <RateController hz="1.0">
          <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="ComputePathToPose">
            <ComputePathToPose goal="{goal}" path="{path}" planner_id="{selected_planner}"/>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </RecoveryNode>
        </RateController>
        <ReactiveSequence name="MonitorAndFollowPath">
          <PathLongerOnApproach path="{path}" prox_len="3.0" length_factor="2.0">
            <RetryUntilSuccessful num_attempts="1">
              <SequenceStar name="CancelingControlAndWait">
                <CancelControl name="ControlCancel"/>
                <Wait wait_duration="5.0"/>
              </SequenceStar>
            </RetryUntilSuccessful>
          </PathLongerOnApproach>
          <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="FollowPath">
            <FollowPath path="{path}" controller_id="{selected_controller}"/>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Context" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
          </RecoveryNode>
        </ReactiveSequence>
      </PipelineSequence>
      <ReactiveFallback name="RecoveryFallback">
        <GoalUpdated/>
        <RoundRobin name="RecoveryActions">
          <Sequence name="ClearingActions">
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </Sequence>
          <Spin spin_dist="1.57"/>
          <Wait wait_duration="5.0"/>
          <BackUp backup_dist="0.30" backup_speed="0.05"/>
        </RoundRobin>
      </ReactiveFallback>
    </RecoveryNode>
  </BehaviorTree>
</root>

My problem is that I can't make the robot to wait. When I put an obstacle dynamically in Gazebo, it recalculates the path and it moves to the goal, instead of waiting for wait_duration parameter inside the CancelingControlAndWait.
You can watch the video from this link.
I added RCLCPP_INFO's but I can't get any log from the node...
inline BT::NodeStatus PathLongerOnApproach::tick()
{
  
  getInput("path", new_path_);
  getInput("prox_len", prox_len_);
  getInput("length_factor", length_factor_);

  if (status() == BT::NodeStatus::IDLE) {
    // Reset the starting point since we're starting a new iteration of
    // PathLongerOnApproach (moving from IDLE to RUNNING)
    first_time_ = true;
  }

  setStatus(BT::NodeStatus::RUNNING);

  // Check if the path is updated and valid, compare the old and the new path length,
  // given the goal proximity and check if the new path is longer
  if (isPathUpdated(new_path_, old_path_) && isRobotInGoalProximity(old_path_, prox_len_) &&
    isNewPathLonger(new_path_, old_path_, length_factor_) && !first_time_)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "isPathUpdated(new_path_, old_path_): %d", isPathUpdated(new_path_, old_path_));
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "isRobotInGoalProximity(old_path_, prox_len_): %d", isRobotInGoalProximity(old_path_, prox_len_));
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "isNewPathLonger(new_path_, old_path_, length_factor_): %d", isNewPathLonger(new_path_, old_path_, length_factor_));
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "!first_time_: %d", !first_time_);
    const BT::NodeStatus child_state = child_node_->executeTick();
    switch (child_state) {
      case BT::NodeStatus::RUNNING:
        return BT::NodeStatus::RUNNING;
      case BT::NodeStatus::SUCCESS:
        old_path_ = new_path_;
        return BT::NodeStatus::SUCCESS;
      case BT::NodeStatus::FAILURE:
        old_path_ = new_path_;
        return BT::NodeStatus::FAILURE;
      default:
        old_path_ = new_path_;
        return BT::NodeStatus::FAILURE;
    }
  }
  old_path_ = new_path_;
  first_time_ = false;
  return BT::NodeStatus::SUCCESS;
}

My Logs...
[rviz2-2] Start navigation
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1729833615.215169490] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigator's default behavior tree.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833615.223856384] [bt_navigator]: Received goal preemption request
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833615.224028176] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (-1.58, -0.54) to (-1.60, -0.53)
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833615.764905618] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833615.872068510] [controller_server]: Reached the goal!
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833615.903716829] [bt_navigator]: Goal succeeded
[rviz2-2] Start navigation
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1729833618.070878386] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigator's default behavior tree.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833618.071428995] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (-1.44, -0.61) to (1.72, -0.50)
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833618.092584848] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833619.192929624] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833620.192965232] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833621.192955122] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833622.292949293] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833623.292972074] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833624.292968832] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833625.392950488] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1729833625.602956268] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 860! 
[component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1729833625.602995757] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: BaseObstacle/Trajectory Hits Obstacle.
[component_container_isolated-1] [WARN] [1729833625.603168948] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 860! 
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833626.392963703] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1729833626.902219404] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 860! 
[component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1729833626.902248553] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: BaseObstacle/Trajectory Hits Obstacle.
[component_container_isolated-1] [WARN] [1729833626.902497489] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 860! 
[component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1729833627.005680683] [DWBLocalPlanner]: No valid trajectories out of 860! 
[component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1729833627.005717964] [DWBLocalPlanner]: 1.00: BaseObstacle/Trajectory Hits Obstacle.
[component_container_isolated-1] [WARN] [1729833627.006040783] [controller_server]: No valid trajectories out of 860! 
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833627.392952896] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833628.392951132] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833629.492967161] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833630.492958709] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833631.492949578] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833632.592951968] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833633.592961333] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833634.592960129] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833635.692975286] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833636.692957272] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833637.692953681] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833638.692956073] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833639.792960641] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833640.792969005] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833641.792957142] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833642.892948724] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833643.892967444] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833644.892963180] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833645.992973924] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833646.992975565] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833647.992965296] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833648.992960271] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833649.904044240] [controller_server]: Reached the goal!
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1729833649.941624765] [bt_navigator]: Goal succeeded


It was related to a commit which hasn't done yet on the Humble version. Not it's fixed. You can see the details in the link.
